# String won't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, methods, parameters

I get a bool value as a parameter and assign it to a variable

```
@package = params[:package]
```

Now, I have a method which should return a string based on the value of `package`. The method looks like this:

```
def get_description(package)
    if package == 1
      "foo"
    elsif package == 2
      "bar"
    end
  end
```

In another method, I try to get the `@description` by:

```
@description = get_description(@package)
```

The problem is, the string is not displayed. The `@description` variable stays empty. Maybe I'm too stupid to see the bug?

Comment: From your code, I assume you mean two-valued (ie, either "1" or "2"), not boolean in the sense of true/false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want you can use your code changing the value of package to integer:

```
def get_description(package)
  package = package.to_i
  if package == 1
    "foo"
  elsif package == 2
    "bar"
  end
end
```

Or using a case statement:

```
def get_description(package)
  case package.to_i
  when 1
    "foo"
  when 2
    "bar"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

All parameters arrive in your controller as *strings*, regardless of what type you think they should be. This is even true if the parameter was originally written to the browser by a View using an Integer. This is just because of the way browsers send the data back to the server.

You'll need to convert the parameter to an integer, or compare it with the strings `"1"` and `"2"`.